# dynamically added label not showing in c#

Tags: c#

I am making an endless randomized platformer game (in  mircosoft visual studio), by using presets of labels.

My "plan" is to create a new label, using all of the properties of the label in the preset (and changing the position of course). Here is my code (assuming "Platform1 is the preset label):

```
        Label newLabel = new Label();
        newLabel.AutoSize = false;            
        newLabel.BackColor = Platform1.BackColor;
        newLabel.Top = Platform1.Top-420;
        newLabel.Left = Platform1.Left;
        newLabel.Size = Platform1.Size;
```

My problem is that **newLabel** isnt showing.

I have tried **Visible = true** and **BringToFront**, with no success.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this Windows Forms? If so, you should tag it with Windows Forms. If not, please tag it with whatever library/framework you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the label to a container control e.g. the `Form` you're running this code on. (`MyForm.Controls.Add(newLabel);`)